# Magento 2 : Stock status not accurate

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, stock

I have some products which they are ***out of stock*** in backend and also in catalog pages, but on the product page, they appear as ***in stock***.

This behavior is the same whether the ***flat product*** enabled or disabled.

I have ***Manage Stock*** enabled and also the ***back orders***

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Like an indexer or a cron job not running?

Comment: No, I don't get any error, all the indexers are running fine and this strange issue exists even if I don't use the flat catalog/categories.